# I use the built-in LoginView of django2.2.7, the user obtained in the request.user of the homepage template and the article template is inconsistent

Tags: session, redis

I use the built-in LoginView of django2.2.7. When the virtual machine and the physical host log in separately, the users obtained in the request.user of the homepage template and the article template are inconsistent, and the session is stored in redis

[image]

模板代码如下
`enter code here`

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}{# 用户未登录时显示 #}
     欢迎,{{ user.username }}
    <a>结果{{ user }}</a>
    <a href="{% url 'Authlogin:logout' %}">登出</a>
    {% if user.is_staff %}
        <a href="http://10.0.0.25:8000/admin/">站点</a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'Authlogin:register' %}" class="regist">注册</a>
    <a href="{% url 'Authlogin:logi`enter code here`n' %}" class="login">登录</a>
{% endif %}</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

github project address
https://github.com/13129/WEB
Project package
django==2.2.7
mysqlclient
redis
django-redis
requests
bs4
numpy
django-imagekit
django-ckeditor
django-debug-toolbar